# Migrating STSProfileCredentialsServiceProvider to AWS SDK v2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Trying to migrate following DynamoDB client code to the new SDK. Unfortunately this provider is not covered by Amazon guide and can't find any other resource. This is all we need with the SDK v1.

```
STSProfileCredentialsServiceProvider credProvider = STSProfileCredentialsServiceProvider(
    RoleInfo()
        .withRoleArn(role)
        .withRoleSessionName(sessionName)
);

return AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withCredentials(credProvider)
    .build();
```

Currently experimenting with `StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider` and `StsProfileCredentialsProviderFactory` but keep getting 403, Access denied.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan yes, we made it work using the StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider. Not sure it is the official 1:1 alternative though. Thus not posting as answer